# How to save user response in DB or External System in watson assistant

Tags: watson-assistant

I'm new in IBM Watson Assistant. I have a use case where i have to ask user for their interest. and i need to save the response in db or call some API and post the user response. any how i want to capture user response in my own system.

I have done basic handson on Watson Assistant. Not able to figure out how to save user response in external system.

If the question is What is your favorite Mobile Brand.
Options: Apple , Samsung , Sony

If user Response with Apple. Then I need to save this in my system. So in future i can offer products according to customer interest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The messages API Response includes everything you'd need. You could store that response in your database each time, or configure your application to only store specific responses (e.g. when a certain intent or entity is detected, since the response includes those data elements).

Put more simply, your application is already controlling the flow of information between the user and the Watson Assistant API, so you're in full control over when and how to capture the API Response data and store it wherever you'd like.

Comment: Hi , I was using GUI / Webportal to learn Watson. I have followed this Link:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-getting-started#getting-started-tutorial

I have also published chatbox Link and also integrated in Facebook Messenger.

I Never tried Implementing API. but it seems that API Integration is only way i can capture user input. Thanks for Suggestion. I will try to Integrate API. :)

Comment: @AnishBarot Yes, you'll need to use the API one way or another. But another approach, and one that might work better in your use case, would be to use the logs endpoint to retrieve the conversation logs (and then parse and store the data you need). This way you wouldn't have to create an entirely new API-based approach to managing the bot app, but could instead leave your current setup alone and just fetch the data you need separately as often as you'd like.

Comment: any documentation or reference is useful than suggesting what possible and not.